# AdomdDataAdapter is hanging

Tags: adomd.net

When a query takes much time, the adomdadapter blocks other code from executing. We are firing async queries on that method and if any query takes much time, it blocks other async operations

Comment: We need a lot more information, like code, queries, client configuration, server config, db schema, tablesizes etc to come even close to an answer

Answer (score 0):

Share you code. Try setting [command timeout](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.adomdserver.adomdcommand.commandtimeout.aspx) and [connection timeout](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.adomdclient.adomdconnection.connectiontimeout.aspx)